# How to make line-clamp-2 work without needing to add 3 words

Tags: css, tailwind-css

https://play.tailwindcss.com/Uj8FMCnfNd?layout=horizontal

That's the link showing 4 examples.
The behavior that I need to make it work, is the one where, when having less then 2 words, and the words are long enough, it breaks in two lines, but it also adds the ellipsis,
Ideally the solution would only use tailwind, but its okay to have custom css in the mix, definitely not javascript should be involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Word Break](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/word-break).

When you set your `line-clamp` to 2, and you have a long word, it will break the word into two lines as well as add the ellipsis.

You can combine the `truncate`, `line-clamp`, and `break` utilities to get different results.

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-[100px_100px_100px_100px] gap-4 ">
  <div class="line-clamp-2 break-all">
    <span>a longgglonggglonggglonggglonggglonggglonggglonggg</span>
  </div>
  <div class="truncate break-all">
    <span>b longgglonggglonggglonggglonggglonggglonggglonggg</span>
  </div>
  <div class="line-clamp-2 break-all">
    <span>c longgglonggglonggglonggglonggglonggglonggglonggg l</span>
  </div>
  <div class="line-clamp-1 break-all">
    <span>d longgglonggglonggglonggglonggglonggglonggglonggg l</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Example Image]

[Tailwind-Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/XdXlWWS1fD)

---

Example of having one long word separated into two lines with ellipsis:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-[100px_100px_100px_100px] gap-4">
  <div class=" break-words line-clamp-2">
    <span>longgglonggglonggglonggglonggglonggglonggglonggg</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Tailwind-Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/XvgkbPbvTa)